# Elementor: need to target a 3 buttons in 3 flip boxes and assign them IDs but cant edit page code

Tags: html, class, elementor

My client's site uses Elementor. The flipboxes have buttons on the backside, but these aren't given IDs, they all have classes.

I need to target these specific buttons and assign them IDs to run a script to open inactive tabs. I had a script that was working with the div ID, but it's only working on the desktop.

Given that it's Elementor and I can't just go in and change the class to an ID, what HTML do I need to change just these classes to their own IDs?

Anything I research doesn't account for Elementor's external code "feature".

The page is https://phparivaca.org/about-2023/

The class I need to target is `.elementor-flip-box__button elementor-button elementor-size-md`.

I've tried just targeting the classes on that page and trying to work around the other flipboxes.